# Show popup from right side and in the same place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used `slideToggle` to show the popup content:

```js
  $( "button" ).click(function() {
            $( "p" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
         });
```

```css
p {
        width: 400px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Toggle</button>
     <p>
     This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You should feel 
     <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in your life.  
     Congratulations!
     </p>
```

I want to show the popup content, appear from right side of screen and hide back.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

put p tag contents to a div and write style to div. try it.  and 1000 in js represents 1 sec. div will fadeout after 1 sec. you can increase it if needed

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>slideToggle demo</title>
     <style>
     p {
        width: 400px;
     }
     .popup{
        position: absolute;
        background: #fff; 
        display: none;
        right: 0;
     }
     body{
        background:#ccc;
     }
     </style>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <button>Toggle</button>

     <div class="popup">
     <p>
     This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You should feel 
     <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in your life.  
     Congratulations!
     </p> 
 </div>
 <script>
     $( "button" ).click(function() { 
        $( ".popup" ).slideToggle().delay(1000).fadeOut();
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i wanted to show the content from right side screen edge to left side.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Include it in your head. then update your html and jQuery just like this.

**HTML:**

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<p class="animated slideInRight">I added these 2 classes on this Tag</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
   $( "p" ).addClass('animated slideInRight').slideToggle( "slow" );
}); // Added this .addClass('animated slideInRight')
```

**CodePen:** 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqvRXB

Comment: @Dennis Please accept this as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("p").animate({width: 'toggle'});
```